# SPSS CTables via macro

Tags: macros, spss

I am new to SPSS macros. I intend on automating CTables production. In the ctables everything remains the same except the variable.

My command is:

```
   CTABLES
   /VLABELS VARIABLES=usevar anzahl gesamt F0passthrough DISPLAY=LABEL
   /TABLE usevar [C][COLPCT.VALIDN '' PCT40.1] + anzahl [C][COUNT '' F40.0] BY gesamt + F0passthrough
   /SLABELS POSITION=ROW
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=usevar anzahl ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=gesamt F0passthrough ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
   filter off.
```

usevar is the variable I aim on exchanging with the macro. (my variables for example are F5 F6 F7)

so i tried:

```
DEFINE !usevar()
F1 F5
!ENDDEFINE.

   CTABLES
   /VLABELS VARIABLES=usevar anzahl gesamt F0passthrough DISPLAY=LABEL
   /TABLE usevar [C][COLPCT.VALIDN '' PCT40.1] + anzahl [C][COUNT '' F40.0] BY gesamt + F0passthrough
   /SLABELS POSITION=ROW
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=usevar anzahl ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=gesamt F0passthrough ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
   filter off.
```

Any help is much appreciated - did not provide sample data. Just need a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you define the macro with the name "`!usevar`", you have to use the same name in the syntax - "`usevar`" won't do.

Anyway I suggest a different approach to the macro:

```
define !MyCtabMacro (!pos=!cmdend)
   CTABLES
   /VLABELS VARIABLES=!1 anzahl gesamt F0passthrough DISPLAY=LABEL
   /TABLE !1 [C][COLPCT.VALIDN '' PCT40.1] + anzahl [C][COUNT '' F40.0] BY gesamt + F0passthrough
   /SLABELS POSITION=ROW
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=!1 anzahl ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=gesamt F0passthrough ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
   filter off. 
!enddefine.
```

Now you can call your macro to create a table for each of your variables, for example:

```
!MyCtabMacro F5.
!MyCtabMacro F6.
```

If you are going to do this for many variables, you can let the macro loop through them:

```
define !MyCtabMacro (!pos=!cmdend)
!do !onevar !in(!1)
   CTABLES
   /VLABELS VARIABLES=!onevar anzahl gesamt F0passthrough DISPLAY=LABEL
   /TABLE !onevar [C][COLPCT.VALIDN '' PCT40.1] + anzahl [C][COUNT '' F40.0] BY gesamt + F0passthrough
   /SLABELS POSITION=ROW
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=!onevar anzahl ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=gesamt F0passthrough ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
   filter off. 
!doend
!enddefine.
```

Now to call the macro:

```
!MyCtabMacro F5 F6 F7 F8 F9.
```

Note: for a macro loop you can't use "`F5 to F9`", you have to list all the variables separately as in my example.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation guide for [DEFINE / ENDDEFINE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define.htm) can be a bit scary at first and so to understand all it's features it's best to play around with examples at first.

I share three examples below, which should give you some indication of where you might be going wrong:

```
GET FILE="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".

/* Example1: Using macro as a global string substitution for variable names */.
DEFINE !MyMac1 () educ jobcat !ENDDEFINE.
FREQ !MyMac1.


/* Example2: Having command in the body of macro with variable input as an argument */.
/* Result: Notice only single FREQ command is run with two variables */.

DEFINE !MyMac2 (VARS=!CMDEND).
SET MPRINT ON.
FREQ !VARS.
SET MPRINT OFF.
!ENDDEFINE.
!MyMac2 vars=educ jobcat.


/* Example3: Having command in the body of macro with variable input as an argument */
/* but looping over each variable */.
/* Result: Notice two separate FREQ commands are run */.
/* with one variable each, i.e. looped for each variable */.

DEFINE !MyMac3 (VARS=!CMDEND).
SET MPRINT ON.
!DO !I !IN (!VARS)
FREQ !i.
!DOEND
SET MPRINT OFF.
!ENDDEFINE.
!MyMac3 vars=educ jobcat.
```

The features of `DEFINE/ENDDEFINE` can be used in various ways. Once you build some knowledge of them all, you'll soon develop a particular style of how you prefer to code your macros. If you are learning SPSS macros for the first time and have some knowledge (or interest in Python) then I would encourage you NOT to start a journey of learning SPSS macros but instead learn python as this type of macro building is much more efficient (and fun!) to code in with Python (amongst many other benefits).

Comment: Thank you a lot for the examples, I´ll  definitly ned to get familiar with the syntax and the macro logic....